# VS Code not showing Java tests in the beaker

Tags: java, unit-testing, visual-studio-code

For a Java [project](https://github.com/brianjmurrell/jenkins-shared-library-example/tree/updates) (`build.gradle` is in the GH project in the link) that I am trying to resurrect, I can successfully run `./gradlew test` and the tests run.  However, when I switch to the **TESTING** extension (the beaker) in VS Code, I don't see any tests such as this [video](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-testing/gutter-icon.mp4) shows.

I do have the *Test Runner for Java* extension installed.

This could very well be PEBKAC error as I am not a Java developer so just trying to pick up the bits and pieces as I can at this moment.

Comment: Hi, Brian. Is your problem solved? Are there any updates?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong in your video.

Right-click to select, and then select the test of your choice in the **Testing** panel.

Comment: That video is not mine.  That video is how it is *supposed* to work.  In my case I don't get the green triangles indicating that VS Code has detected my tests.

Comment: This displays fine on [my machine](https://imgur.com/a/wgsWCmp) (except for those error messages). Install the [Java Extension Pack](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscjava.vscode-java-pack) for the latest version, or try installing a [pre-release version](https://imgur.com/UM4OuwM).